# I want to run exe file in C# asp.net (mvc)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to run a .exe file in C# asp.net (mvc). I was able to run that particular .exe file but it file needs the other files which were in my computer's directory.

How can I add that directory to my project? [This is my running project. The exe file can't find the files which the .exe files needs to execute.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ppef4.png)

The following is the code which I can run the .exe file from my PC.

```
public string Onclick()
    {

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\Talha\Desktop\New folder\linkedin\server";
        p.Start();
       // ProcessInfo.Start(@"C:\Users\Talha\Desktop\New folder\linkedin\server.exe");
        return "BUTTON ONCLICK";
    }
```

Comment: Talha,  where is your "links1.txt" file located? Is it included in the folder where the executable is?

Comment: Are you expecting this MVC site to run executables on the client?

Comment: @Shai Aharoni
"links1.txt" file located "C:\Users\Talha\Desktop\New folder\linkedin" where my exe file(server.exe) exist. yes it is included in the folder where the  executable is.

Comment: @Crowcoder 
for now I want to run my executable on client side.
but after that I want to run my EXE to run on server side.

Comment: @TalhaAhmed , and where is your server.py file is located? This is the file that raises the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write this address:

```
"C:\Users\Talha\Desktop\New%20folder\linkedin\server.exe"
```